# Write contents of 2 variables into file with 2 lines using this Lua script

Tags: lua

In a Lua script I have 2 variables (var1 and var2) that each contain values from a table.

```
    local var2 = (table.concat(itmes_A, " "))
    local var3 = (table.concat(items_B, " "))
```

I need to write a file with 2 lines. First line for var1, second line for var2.

Currently my Lua code to write to the file (var1_2.txt) all on one line. Code is as follows:

```
    local communicatorFile
        communicatorFile = "D:\\Windows\\temp\\var1_2.txt"
        local createFile = assert(io.open(communicatorFile,"w+"))
        createFile:write(var2)
        createFile:write(var3)
        createFile:close()
```

What's needed to get the variables on one line each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert `createFile:write('\r\n')`

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
createFile:write(var2)
createFile:write(var3)
```

to have a new-line character with them.

```
createFile:write(var2.."\r\n")
createFile:write(var3)
```

Note that you can just use `\n` instead of `\r\n`; but your Notepad wouldn't recognise it as a new-line character.